# Architecture for ListView to GridView containing photos (click on ListItem to go to GridView with photos)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, photos

I am trying to implement architecture for when a user clicks on a ListView item which will then take them to a GridView where they can upload photos to. Like so:

[image]

I am thinking to implement a `setOnClickListener` onto each item via:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
..... // Initializing and setting adapter to ListView
listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this, GridViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Or would it be better to setup an `OnClickItemListener` in my `Adapter` class?

Then what would be the best implementation for setting up a `GridView` which would contain multi variable photos like this:

[image]

I have little experience with `GridView`, but have experience with the Camera Library.

Comment: https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

Comment: SilentKiller I haven't tried any actual code yet I just wanted to get an understanding of high level design before I started coding.

Comment: Pratik Butani thanks for the link!! I want to create it myself though without someone else's help so I can learn better